# Permalink is not working in sub-subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a sub-subdomain (looks like xxx.yyy.zzz.com), i've installed wordpress 3.6 and set permalink settings to "Day and name", then create .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but when i click some pages at frontpage it returns error page like:

Not Found

The requested URL /aboutus/ was not found on this server.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: is the url xxx.yyy.zzz.com/aboutus/ as expected? Or is it just zzz.com/aboutus/

Answer (score 1):

Try the plugin *wordpress seo yoast*, it could help you set the permanent url format. i could not promise that it can solve your problem absolutely, but you could have a try. ^_^